# Recursively update parent and sort item value

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending an object array to the server side for drag and drop menu ordering. I want to update each menu item's **parent_id** and it's **sort** value into my database and all root items parent will be 0, but I can't define my function correctly.

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried with

```
public static function sort($menus, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        $menuItem = MenuItem::find($menu['id']);
        $menuItem->parent_id = $parent_id;
        $menuItem->sort = $i;
        $menuItem->save();
        $i += $i;
        if (count($menu['children'])) {
            MenuController::sort($menus, $menu['id']);
        }
    }
}

public function postSaveMenuOrder(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('menu-data')) {
        $menuData = $request->get('menu-data');
        MenuController::sort($menuData);
    }
}
```

Comment: change  $i += $i;    with    $i  = $i + 1;

Comment: my method gives wrong output,
id->parent_id->sort,
2->0->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0,
2->2->0, ... ... ...  @ehsan

Comment: if   if (count($menu['children'])) {
            MenuController::sort($menus, $menu['id']);
        }    -- use     :     MenuController::sort($menu['children'], $menu['id']);

Comment: if (count($menu['children'])) {
    $tmp = $menu['id'] . '->' . $parent_id . '->' . $i . '</br>';
    echo $tmp;
    $i = $i + 1;
    MenuController::sort($menu['children'], $menu['id'],$i);
} 

Output: id->parent_id->sort,2->0->0,1->2->1 function stoped.

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains objects but you are trying to use them as arrays:

```
public static function sort($menus, $parent_id = 0)
{
    foreach ($menus as $key => $menu) {
        $menuItem = MenuItem::find($menu->id);
        $menuItem->parent_id = $parent_id;
        $menuItem->sort = $key;
        $menuItem->save();

        if (count($menu->children)) {
            // note that here we are passing the children of the menu, 
            // not all the menus as in your example
            self::sort($menu->children, $menu->id);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use the key instead of a the `$i` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response,it does not work. @Matei Mihai

Comment: What is not working? do you  have any error thrown? what's the behaviour?

Comment: Finally I have solved my problem. public function sort($menus, $parent_id = 0, &$i = 0)
{
    foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        $tmp = $menu['id'] . '->' . $parent_id . '->' . $i . '</br>';
        echo $tmp;
        $i = $i + 1;
        if (array_key_exists('children', $menu)) {
            $this->sort($menu['children'], $menu['id'], $i);
        }
    }
}

Comment: You don't need the sort key to be incremented for each menu and submenu.. each submenu order can start from 0